# Exclude Combination of Data Items From One Table From Another

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a view, A, with 20 columns which forms my primary data. I have a table B which lists some of the columns from A and contains data I want to exclude from A.

For example table B will have 6 columns 2 of which are 'customer' and 'country' and contain the data 'HP' and 'America'. These columns exist in A. But I want to write a query that brings back data from A except where any rows that have a combination HP and America.

There are 6 columns and table B can have any combination of rows. Anywhere between 1 and all 6 rows could be filled in or there could be a row which has 5 columns filled in. Also another row with a different 5 columns filled in and so on.

I want to be prepared for any possible combination of the 6 rows and the query to search A for the combination and exclude any rows with that data from B.

I have tried this

```
SELECT *
FROM A T1
WHERE not  EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ExcludedItems] T2
    WHere ReportNumber=1
    AND
    (              
        T1.job=ISNULL(T2.job,T1.job) and T1.CustomerName=ISNULL(T2.CustomerName,T1.CustomerName) and
        T1.COUNTRY= ISNULL(T2.COUNTRY,T1.COUNTRY) and T1.CONTINENT=ISNULL(T2.CONTINENT,T1.CONTINENT) AND
        T1.continer= ISNULL(T2.ContainerName, T1.continer) and T1.UnscheduledJob= ISNULL(T2.unscheduledJob, T1.UnscheduledJob) and
        T1.[Price]= ISNULL(T2.Price, T1.Price) and
        T1.[Haulage]= ISNULL(T2.[Haulage], T1.[Haulage]) and
        T1.SiteAdress= ISNULL(T2.SiteAddress, T1.SiteAdress) and T1.Delta=ISNULL(T2.Delta, T1.Delta) and
        T1.Cost= ISNULL(T2.Cost, T1.Cost)
    )

)
```

The problem is the result set is not correct. I have tried with a smaller column sample and able to exclude the correct combination of Customer and Country but when I introduce a 3rd or 4th column combination I can eyeball the result set and immediately see its incorrect. Not sure if I have to use multiple `NOT EXISTS` for each possible combination, was hoping not to.

A constraint is A has to be a view not a table. Otherwise I would have used variables in some manner and wrapped the whole thing in a stored procedure.

Appreciate any help, fall back is to manually add to the code each time an item combination is supplied in B!

Comment: should the 3rd be `T1.COUNTRY= ISNULL(T2.COUNTRY,T1.COUNTRY)` instead of `T1.COUNTRY= ISNULL(T2.COUNTRY,T1.SupplierName)`?

Comment: Sorry yes it should. I was playing around with the combinations and missed one from my copying and pasting column names.